# let vs regular assignment in GHCi

Tags: haskell

Is there any difference between

```
f x = x + 1
```

and

```
let f x = x + 1
```

when typed into GHCi? IIUC, there's a special rule that `let` without `in` inside `GHCi` effectively applies to the entire scope of the interpreter. But if the presence of `let` makes no difference, what's the point of this rule?

Edit: using GHCi version 8.0.2.

Comment: Which version of GHCi? Mine doesn't accept `f x = x + 1` as a input (parse error).

Comment: @Mephy It's new in GHC 8.

Comment: As I understand it, having to use `let` to bind names in GHCi is an effect of how it is implemented. You can imagine you're entering commands into a "do-block" in the IO monad.

Comment: @Erik I'm not she that that is how it's actually implemented (I believe you're not directly entering statements in an IO do block, rather there's an IO action in GHCi's code that is interpreting your statements). But it's certainly deliberate that the syntax is based on do block syntax.

Comment: The manual discusses this: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, there's no difference.

It used to be that ghci was essentially an open-ended IO do block. But the inability to define new types in this syntax form, and the need to write `let` for every definition, were seen as annoying restrictions that often got in the way of everyday interactive use, and so the syntax of ghci has slowly become more permissive. But it is just a syntax change -- nothing deep.

However, there is one thing to be aware of: if you want to start a block, you must do that explicitly. For example,

```
> f [] = 3
> f (x:xs) = 4
```

is equivalent to

```
> let f [] = 3
> let f (x:xs) = 4
```

and not

```
> :{
| let f [] = 3
|     f (x:xs) = 4
| :}
```

hence will be a *new* definition of `f` that shadows the old one and is only defined on non-empty lists, whereas you probably meant to give two equations for a single `f`. With automatic block mode (`:set +m`), ghci can notice that `let` started a block and automatically give you the latter when you type `let`, thus:

```
> let f [] = 3
|     f (x:xs) = 4
|
```

It will not do this for short-form (non-`let`) definitions.

Answer (score 2):

Although this question was asked months ago, I do notice some more difference when I start to learn Haskell recently.

```
> :set -Wall
> a = 2
> let a = 3
```

results in a warning about **name shadowing** (*-Wname-shadowing*), while

```
> :set -Wall
> a = 2
> a = 3
```

does not. It seems that the warning only checks for explicitly written `let` statements.

Answer (score 2):

Another difference:

```
λ> x = 1 :: Int
λ> :sprint x
x = _
λ> let x = 1 :: Int
λ> :sprint x
x = 1
```